# how to dump a json dict completely? (so far just dumpt last page )

Tags: python

I couldn't dump the json dict completly
I just could dump the json dict last page. Help me,please.
the coding showed below:

```
def job_list(url):
    htmlFile = requests.get(url)
    objSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlFile.text,'lxml')
    jobs = objSoup.find_all('article',class_='js-job-item')
    job_list = []
    for job in jobs:        
        cust_name = job.get('data-cust-name')
        print("公司名稱:",cust_name)
        job_name = job.get('data-job-name')
        print("職稱名稱:",job_name)
        d = [('公司名稱',cust_name),('職務名稱', job_name)]
        j_dict = dict(d)
        job_list.append(j_dict)
     

       
url_H = 'https://www.104.com.tw/jobs/search/?ro=0&kwop=7&keyword=藥師&order=1&asc=0&page='
url_T = '&mode=s&jobsource=2021indexpoc'
page_total = 2
for page in range(page_total):
        url = url_H+str(page+1)+url_T
        job_list(url)
        print('-'*70)
        time.sleep(random.randint(3,5))
        
myjob = {'Job':job_list}

fn = '104爬蟲.json'
with open(fn, "w") as fnObj:
    json.dump(myjob,fnObj,indent=2,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: You're re-initiating the list here `job_list = []` every time you call `job_list()`. You probably want to initialize the list outside of the function, and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
jobs_to_dump = []   #### added 

def job_list(url):
    htmlFile = requests.get(url)
    objSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlFile.text, 'lxml')
    jobs = objSoup.find_all('article', class_='js-job-item')
    job_list = []
    for job in jobs:
        cust_name = job.get('data-cust-name')
        print("公司名稱:", cust_name)
        job_name = job.get('data-job-name')
        print("職稱名稱:", job_name)
        d = [('公司名稱', cust_name), ('職務名稱', job_name)]
        j_dict = dict(d)
        jobs_to_dump.append(j_dict)  ###modified



url_H = 'https://www.104.com.tw/jobs/search/?ro=0&kwop=7&keyword=藥師&order=1&asc=0&page='
url_T = '&mode=s&jobsource=2021indexpoc'
page_total = 2 

for page in range(page_total):
    url = url_H + str(page + 1) + url_T
    job_list(url)
    print('-' * 70)
    time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))

myjob = {'Job': jobs_to_dump}  #### modified

fn = '104爬蟲.json'
with open(fn, "w") as fnObj:
    json.dump(myjob, fnObj, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```